# Clashing keybinding byobu and vdebug vim

Tags: byobu, vim-plugin

I am using byobu as a window manager and am also using the 'joonty/vdebug' vim plugin as a debugger. In order to start the debugger the keybinding is F5 but inside byobu when I press F5 I get a message saying

```
Set option: prefix2 -> C-a
```

How do I make the vim plugin keybindings work inside byobu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily disable <kbd>F5</kbd> in [Byobu](http://byobu.co) by adding this one line to the file `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`:

```
unbind-key -n F5
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*